# Symfony 2/3 Route not found with trailing slash

Tags: symfony

I have the following route:

```
product_category:
  path: /{grandFatherSlug}/{fatherSlug}/{childSlug}
  defaults: { _controller: ProductCategory:productCategoryPage, fatherSlug: "",  childSlug: ""}
  options:
```

I want this kind of routes ends with a trailing slash, because of SEO recommendations. 
But I cannot make it works. I have tried with:

```
product_category:
  path: /{grandFatherSlug}/{fatherSlug}/{childSlug}/
  defaults: { _controller: ProductCategory:productCategoryPage, fatherSlug: "",  childSlug: ""}
  options:
```

But I get a route not found exception and with:

```
product_category:
  path: /{grandFatherSlug}/{fatherSlug}/{childSlug}/
  defaults: { _controller: ProductCategory:productCategoryPage, fatherSlug: "",  childSlug: ""}
  requirements:
    childSlug: .+
    fatherSlug: .+
    grandFatherSlug: .+
```

but I get the final parameter with the trailing slash appended, what makes me to call str_replace in the Controller to remove it.

Is any easy solution to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to avoid `/` in your regular expression?

```
product_category:
  path: /{grandFatherSlug}/{fatherSlug}/{childSlug}/
  defaults: { _controller: ProductCategory:productCategoryPage, fatherSlug: "",  childSlug: ""}
  requirements:
    childSlug: [.+^\/]
    fatherSlug: .+
    grandFatherSlug: .+
```